# How to search Github for pull request by PR number?

Tags: github

I used to be able to search github by pull request number.

This number is used in the pull request url as an identifier and it appears in gray by each pull request `#XXX`.

I used to be able to search `is:pr is:closed 1234` and get results of pull requests with the string 1234 in the pull request itself along with pull request #1234 would appear.
I have lost the result for PR #1234 and I am trying to figure out how to get this functionality back.

Comment: Changing the number in the url?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the PR number, you can just go to the URL (unless you for some reason need it to necessarily access it from the search function):

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repository-name>/pull/<pr-number>
```

Comment: This is a solution.  As far as I know, accessing it from the search function is functionality that has disappeared on github.com